# failure - executing bat file in jenkins

Tags: selenium, batch-file, jenkins

I am trying to execute a simple .bat file in jenkins - selserver.bat (The bat file executes the selenium standalone server) using 'Execute windows batch command'. Under that, in Execute shell, I have my automation test cases that will use the selenium server. But when i run the job, I get this error

````
    New build name is '#Sel_job'
       [#Sel_job] $ cmd /c call /tmp/hudson1913007337035643872.bat
       FATAL: command execution failed
         java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory   "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/#Sel_job"): error=2, No such file or directory
         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
         at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
         at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
         at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
         at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
         at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:108)
         at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:65)
         at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
         at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
         at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
         at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
         at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
         at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
         at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
         at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
         at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:401)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
         at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
         at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
         at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
          ... 15 more```
````

What I dont understand is why is jenkins trying to get some hudsonXXXX.bat in the tmp location? because I have only selserver.bat in my config. How should I fix this. Appreciate all answers in advance!

Comment: The path in the exception and the presence of `UNIXProcess` in the stack trace suggests that Jenkins is not running on a Windows machine.  Perhaps you need a shell script instead?

Comment: yes. that is correct. So what is the way to start selenium server from jenkins (it should start as a standalone server). Then my automation test cases have to run using that server